# Celery - No module named 'celery.datastructures'

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

i am using `Django 1.10` + `celery==4.0.0rc3` + `django-celery with commit @79d9689b62db3d54ebd0346e00287f91785f6355` .

My settings are:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
# http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#visibility-timeout
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 259200}  # 3 days
```

my tasks.py i have

```
@task(queue='assign_rnal_id')
def assign_rnal_id_to_mongo(rnal_id, mongo_id):
    print ("something")

    return False
```

In my django model i am overriding the save method to send a task to celery:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Suggested, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        assign_rnal_id_to_mongo.delay(rnal_id=self.id, mongo_id=self.raw_data['_id'])
```

When i save my model object i get a `No module named 'celery.datastructures'`

Any ideas?? I have similar code working for older versions of django and celery, did something change?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using django 1.10 and Celery 4.0.x I needed to

```
pip install django-celery-results
pip install django-celery-beat
```

That fixed the issue for me with out needing to downgrade my Celery.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to monitor the Workers status with these packages?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer here https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3303#issuecomment-246780116

Basically `Django-celery does not support 4.0 yet` so i downgraded to `celery==3.1.23` and it now works

Comment: Yes! Django-celery has been replaced by two new libraries for 4.0: django-celery-results and django-celery-beat.  We'll probably make django-celery work before the release so it works, but there's been lots of confusion of when django-celery is necessary, and now the answer is never.